# CSS not found in PHP localhost

Tags: php, html, css, localhost

[image][image]For the life of me I can't not make my CSS populate in my index.php file via localhost. Everything is populated in the local host except the CSS properites and the image for the avatar which is supplied through the html/php form not CSS. I was about to start the process of connecting email with the contact from, but hit a road block of not having the CSS connected. In the page source it says "Object Not Found," "Error 404 localhost
Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.1"

Im not sure how I can fix this. I am very new to this- I just downloaded XAMPP today so that i can test the php email setup through my local host. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my file path:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Contact</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="contact.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">



</head>
```

Comment: are you sure contact.css is not in a folder.for example (css folder)

Comment: It's in a main folder, however when i add it in, it still can't be found. link href="MunozWeb/contact.css"

Comment: How is the arborescense of your project ?

Comment: what does arborescense mean?

Comment: I want say the tree or structure of your project. Where is `contact.css` compared to the file who use it ?

Comment: Please look at the upper and lower case.!!!

Comment: Windows is not case sensitive !

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by structure so I've added a screen shot of my folders. The main project folder is MunozWeb and the CSS file is located in there. The PHP file is index.php, I have href the CSS file in the php file. The index file is loading on the localhost but not CSS.

Comment: Are you sure `contact.css` is not loaded ? I'm seeing the use of `bootstrap` in your project, I can understand by this that contact.css is just used to do a brief customization like font size or color of elements.

Are you sur what animate.css contains is functionable ?

Comment: Compared to the structure of your project, your code should be work very well.

Comment: Thanks Goms on saying it should work. I thought I had everything in place correctly, however I'm getting a error when clicking on the css file in page source. I attached a screen shot. Can this have anything to do with XAMPP? Or the way I'm titling the contact.css form itself?

Comment: No ! It's so clear that `localhost/contact.css` return a `404 error`... If you use xamp and xamp is installed in his default directory `C;\xampp`, `contact.css` is on `C:\xampp\htdocs\contact.css` ? I don't think...

Comment: I only have my idex.php file in the htdocs area since the contact.css is inside the index.php file- this should work, yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164056/discussion-between-goms-and-alexandra).

Comment: W.r.t. the chat: if you've got it working now, you can answer your own question with how you did it. That may help future visitors too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'll go ahead and answer my own question. I turned out that my project file was not placed in the actual XAMPP folder. So tip to all the newbies out there, make sure you put your whole project folder in XAMPP. Worked perfectly after that.